# How to retain a variable when page expires

Tags: jsf-2.2

Hi have a variable stored on the session which contains information on which stylesheet to use.

When the session times out I want to retain the same stylesheet on the "sessionExpired" page. How is the best way to do this?

Comment: I have intentionally left off how I have tried so that the answer doesn't aim towards fixing my attempted solution as there may be a better one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it needs to transcend the session, then I'd suggest not storing it in the session at all. Use a separate cookie.